# Can't connect to RDS after changing size

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance that I was able to connect to remotely fine for months now. However, tonight I downsized the DB because we we're paying for a lot of unused CPU. After the change from m3.medium to the t2.small I can't connect to it anymore. I have terminal shortcuts setup so I can't be typoing it. I double checked the security groups and thats still applied and the host is the same and everything. I'm not sure what else to try. I just get:

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<my-host>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)`

Comment: maybe you are getting the old IP from a DNS cache

Comment: I ran `sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache` and tried again and it didn't work, but Im not sure that would for sure do it. I'm trying to find the IP address now. They don't seem to list it anywhere

Comment: @BretzL whoops, forgot to tag you

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today. After upsizing the RDS instance, I am unable to connect to it using SSMS which I was able to do just a few hours earlier. It has suddenly stopped working on two PCs so I could not have accidentally changed some parameters. However the web server accessing the RDS within the VPC works fine

Answer (score 0):

sorry for silly question: are you sure my-host didn't change after resizing? Given the error message, it's *not* credentials. So, it is either address, or security groups, or VPC-based networking.

Comment: AFAIK its identical. The security group listed is the same for sure, it says  "MyServiceName Prod" which is correct. I checked the actual security group as well and it matches what it was before. I don't do anything with VPC. And I tried copy and pasting the address provided in the console to make sure it didn't change, but I still get that :\